# @Media for image design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working on a site and I have two images that need to be `inline` when device width is more than 425px `(min-width: 425px)` but for some reason it does not seem to be working how it should be and my css with the `@media` but it doesn't work for some reason although it is fairly basic

**CODE**

```css
.info-img {
  width: 49.75%;
}
.info-images {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and only (max-width: 425px) {
  .info-img {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
  .info-images {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="info-images">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dd5exdwwpa13yxnthg/unspecified-4.jpeg?dl=0" class="info-img">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fo3bt6ruhx4qppztho/unspecified-6.jpeg?dl=0" class="info-img">
</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
  @import url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ikcsorhvohzdipo/information.css?dl=0');
</style>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What is it giving you and what do you expect?

Comment: At the moment when device width is more than  425 it works perfectly but when below 425 it seems to not execute the code as the images aren't 100% width and just don't look right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are giving `inline-block` to parent instead of `img`, plus you are writing your media wrongly (its not `@media screen and only`, but `@media only screen and`).

#### Snippet

```css
.info-images {
  font-size: 0;
  /* fix inline-block gap */
}
.info-img {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /* may be necessary */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 1%
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .info-img {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
  .info-images {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="info-images">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" class="info-img">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" class="info-img">
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't work as it doesn't go block when the browser is less than 425px

Comment: You my friend are confusing us, your question say one thing (above 425px) in your 2 comments you ask below 425px, so what you really want?

Comment: Anywhow see my updated answer, you have your media query wrongly written.

Comment: Omg sorry, still learning I'm a 14 year old student whose been coding for no more than a year so still getting use to it, To confirm I want

Comment: When device width is less than 425px display pictures block and when it exceeds 425px display inline-block

Comment: That's  how my Snippet is behaving :) let me know if this solve your issue.

Comment: As well I would like a small gap between the images say a pixel, could you update your code so this works

Comment: when they are `inline-block` above 425px ?

Comment: Yeah thats all like the gap for the block view

Comment: but for 'inline-block'